# MIPS asm syntax - how to address lower 16 bits?

Tags: assembly, mips

when using offset+reg with `sw` instruction, the offset has to be signed 16 bit. How do I express it in an acceptable form? The GNU `as` complains the `expression is too complex`. Note that I do *not* want to use macro instructions.

In fact, these 2 instructions are what macro instr `sw   $0, foo` expands to.

```
lui $1, (foo >> 16)         ; <---- OK
sw $0, (foo & 0xFFFF)($1)   ; <---- error: expr too complex ;)

...

foo:
.word 123
```

Comment: There should be `%hi()` and `%lo()` operators in the GNU assembler (i.e. `%lo(foo)`). Not sure if those would work in your case, and I don't have a MIPS-targeting GAS handy to test it myself.

Comment: @Michael pls post this as answer so i can give you credit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU assembler for MIPS targets has two operators called `%lo` and `%hi` for getting the low and high halfword of an address.

So in your case, the usage would be (untested):

```
lui $1, %hi(foo)         
sw $0, %lo(foo)($1)
```

Comment: i cannot believe i didnt see these ops after browsing `as` manual 20 times!